Heading on Carousel Images


var $item = $('.carousel .item'); 
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight); 
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

//Pause/play buttons

 $(document).ready(function(){
  //$("#mycarousel").carousel( { interval: 2000 } );
  $("#carousel-pause").click(function(){
    $("#mycarousel").carousel('pause');
  });

  $("#carousel-play").click(function(){
    $("#mycarousel").carousel('cycle');
  });
});
.carousel {background:#444;}
.carousel-item .img-fluid {width:100%; max-height: 70vh;}
.carousel-item a {display: block; width:100%;}
header p{color: #20317f; background: white; padding: 1em; border: thin #828280; border-radius: 40px;}
header h1, h2, h3{color: #20317f; background: white; padding: .1em 0em; border: thin #828280; border-radius: 40px;}
<div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
         <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="pics/tags.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
           <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div>
             <h2 style="color: #20317f">Plastic Valve Tags</h2>
              <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
           <img src="pics/logic.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
            <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div>
              <h2 style="color: #20317f">Plastic Panel Labels</h2><br>
               <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
           <img src="pics/skate.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
            <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div>
              <h2 style="color: #20317f">Plastic Control Panel Facing</h2>
               <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="pics/warn.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
             <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div>
               <h2>Plastic Warning Labels</h2>
                <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
             <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="pics/more.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
             <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div>
               <h2>And More</h2>
                <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
           </a>
           <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
           </a>
          </div>



My carousel Headings are all ontop of the images, I'd like for them to be below the images but still within the carousel so that they move as one.
The carousel works so its a styling issue not broken code :)
I'm very new at JavaScript so it could be as simple as the JavaScript places the Headers where they are but I can't figure out how to reposition them:/
This is my HTML for the Carousel, It works perfectly i solely have issue with the heading placement.
<div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
         <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="pics/tags.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
           <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div>
             <h2 style="color: #20317f">Plastic Valve Tags</h2>
              <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
           <img src="pics/logic.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
            <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div>
              <h2 style="color: #20317f">Plastic Panel Labels</h2><br>
               <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
           <img src="pics/skate.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
            <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div>
              <h2 style="color: #20317f">Plastic Control Panel Facing</h2>
               <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="pics/warn.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
             <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div>
               <h2>Plastic Warning Labels</h2>
                <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
             <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="pics/more.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
             <div class="carousel-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div>
               <h2>And More</h2>
                <a href="contact.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact to Order</button></a>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
           </a>
           <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
           </a>
          </div>

This is the CSS
.carousel {background:#444;}
.carousel-item .img-fluid {width:100%; max-height: 70vh;}
.carousel-item a {display: block; width:100%;}
header p{color: #20317f; background: white; padding: 1em; border: thin #828280; border-radius: 40px;}
header h1, h2, h3{color: #20317f; background: white; padding: .1em 0em; border: thin #828280; border-radius: 40px;}

Note: I had to add a white background to the headings for them to be legible in their current position, but this obviously means all headings on the entire site have a white box :/
And here is the JavaScript
var $item = $('.carousel .item'); 
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight); 
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

//Pause/play buttons

 $(document).ready(function(){
  //$("#mycarousel").carousel( { interval: 2000 } );
  $("#carousel-pause").click(function(){
    $("#mycarousel").carousel('pause');
  });
   
  $("#carousel-play").click(function(){
    $("#mycarousel").carousel('cycle');
  });
});


Welcome to Stack Overflow! We would need a minimally working example. So, please create a code snippet with the <> button in the editor. Are you using Bootstrap and JQuery; what are the CDNs attached to your site for the Carousel to work? We would need those too to see the issue in action, in order to better help you.

@iorgv I added the snippet, it's not jQuery or Bootstrap but those are used elsewhere on the site. I'm not sure what CDNs are?

FYI: Nesting button into a, or the other way around, is not allowed in HTML, as they are both considered "interactive" elements.

It looks like you are using the standard Bootstrap carousel, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#captions The captions are absolute positioned by default, so you would either need to overwrite that formatting, or not give them the class carousel-caption in the first place.

@CBroe ah thanks it may be that the code used for the carousel was derived from bootstrap, I just found one of the free-to-use ones online as the bootstrap standard wasn't functional.  I will change the class to avoid the auto positioning thanks:)

@CBroe sorry didnt see your first comment, is there a reason as to why its not allowed cuz it works?

Because they are both considered interactive elements, that each are supposed to serve a specific purpose. A link is supposed to link somewhere, and a button is supposed to trigger some action, like a form submission. When both get nested, situations can arise in which it would not be clear, which of the two actions is supposed to happen.

@CBroe thanks for the help will update all once I have trialed the code again:)

@CBroe  thanks for helping. Changing the carousel-caption class fixed the issue:)

The correct answer was the use of the 'carousel-caption' class in the code auto-positioning the headers. Changing this to 'car-caption' solved the issue. The buttons were also used incorrectly and have been updated here is the corrected code for anyone with the same issue:)


var $item = $('.carousel .item'); 
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight); 
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

//Pause/play buttons

 $(document).ready(function(){
  //$("#mycarousel").carousel( { interval: 2000 } );
  $("#carousel-pause").click(function(){
    $("#mycarousel").carousel('pause');
  });
   
  $("#carousel-play").click(function(){
    $("#mycarousel").carousel('cycle');
  });
});
.carousel {background:#444;}
.carousel-item .img-fluid {width:100%; max-height: 70vh;}
.carousel-item a {display: block; width:100%;}
header p{color: #20317f; background: white; padding: 1em; border: thin #828280; border-radius: 40px;}
header h1, h2, h3{color: #20317f;}
<div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
         <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="pics/tags.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
           <div class="car-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div>
             <h2 style="color: #20317f" align="center"><a href="contact.html">Plastic Valve Tags</a></h2><br>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
           <img src="pics/logic.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
            <div class="car-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div>
              <h2 style="color: #20317f" align="center"><a href="contact.html">Plastic Panel Labels</a></h2><br>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
           <img src="pics/skate.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
            <div class="car-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
             <div>
              <h2 style="color: #20317f" align="center"><a href="contact.html">Plastic Control Panel Facing</a></h2><br>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="pics/warn.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
             <div class="car-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div>
               <h2 align="center"><a href="contact.html">Plastic Warning Labels</a></h2><br>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
             <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="pics/more.png" alt="responsive image" class="d-block img-fluid">
             <div class="car-caption justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div>
               <h2 align="center"><a href="contact.html">And More</a></h2><br>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="car-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
           </a>
           <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="car-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
           </a>
          </div>



